# gksu cannot be run within some directories

Tags: bash, shell

I have set up a self-extracting archive in bash. It requires gksu to run the installation script, and the gksu (and related binaries) are already placed within the archive. The introductory script is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
echoerr ()
{
    echo "$1" >& 2
}

arch_print ()
{
    tail -n +__LINENUM__ "$0"
}

[ "`arch_print | cksum | grep -Eo '^[0-9]+'`" != "__CHECKSUM__" ] && {
    echoerr "Archive integrity check failed!"
    exit 2
}

case `uname -m` in
    i?86)
        export MTYPE="i386"
    ;;
    amd64 | x86_64)
        export MTYPE="amd64"
    ;;
    *)
        echoerr "Unsupported architecture."
        exit 1
    ;;
esac

export installer_dir="/tmp/xxinstaller.`head -c 100 /dev/urandom | tr -cd '[A-Za-z0-9]' | head -c 5`"
{
    mkdir -p "$installer_dir" && arch_print | tar -xjf - -C "$installer_dir"
} || {
    echoerr "Self-extraction failure!"
    exit 2
}

export PATH="$installer_dir/bin/$MTYPE:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$installer_dir/lib/$MTYPE"
gksu-run-helper &

cmd=\"$installer_dir/installer.sh\"
[ `id -n` != "0" ] && cmd="gksu -S $cmd"
$cmd
rm -r "$installer_dir"
exit
###...archive contents...
```

(`__LINENUM__` and `__CHECKSUM__` being replaced while compiling the script into an SFX).

Now, if I try to run this, I get:

```
~/xx-installer$ ./xxinstaller.sh
```

`gksu`'s prompt is displayed and I type in the password. I get:

```
(gksu:4161): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_str_has_prefix: assertion 'str != NULL' failed
```

But I don't have any problems while doing all this manually:

```
~/xx-installer$ PATH=~/xx-installer/bin/i386/:$PATH
~/xx-installer$ gksu-run-helper &
[1] 4279
~/xx-installer$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/xx-installer/lib/i386 gksu -S synaptic # synaptic runs fine
[1]+  Exit 1                  gksu-run-helper
```

How would I correct the above described issue?

Comment: add `echo $cmd` before executing it

Comment: `echo $cmd` gives `gksu -S "/tmp/xxinstaller.O5nsK/installer.sh"`.

Comment: what is `gksu-run-helper`? Could it work with system installed gksu?

Comment: @keltar, gksu-run-helper is a binary required by gksu. And system gksu obviously works, but my users may not have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that its easier to make a GUI frontend for `sudo` myself than having to carry gksu around. The implementation can be somewhat like:

```
pw=`yad --entry --hide-text`
echo $pw | sudo -Sk command
```

Obviously this is only a POC, not a fully worked solution.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem, and way you run `gksu-run-helper` (in background) don't look too promising to me (I don't even have this binary in my system, with `gksu` installed).

But anyway, your problem appears to be with `\"` sign in path. Quotes handled by shell to determine beginning and ending of separate command arguments when argument itself contain spaces within it; this symbols are *not* included into arguments themselves (when used in command). E.g. when you run `ls "/"`, it will actually launch `ls /` and work correctly; but if you try `ls \"/\"` - it will be expanded to `ls "/"`, and will fail because there is no such file or directory (named `"/"` - starting with doublequotes).

So, your code should be like:

```
cmd="$installer_dir/installer.sh"
[ `id -n` != "0" ] && cmd="gksu -S \"$cmd\""
sh -c "$cmd"
```

Extra `sh` will perform second string expansion, handling quotes in process.

Comment: Which distro is this? In all the distros I use (Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS) there is `gksu-run-helper`.

Comment: this binary is in `/usr/lib/libgksu/`. Maybe you were looking for it using `which`?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was looking at package's files list, but it belongs to libgksu. But anyway, it is side question, it is only slightly interferes with yours.